# Is preposition 'for' necessary?

Tags: prepositions

We have a sentence:

> *"I have been out **for** two hours!"*

Is **"for"** necessary here? Can we say:

> *"I have been out two hours!"*

I am asking because we can either ask *"How long have you been out?"* or *"For how long have you been out?"* as far as I know. And probably even *"How long have you been out for?"*.

Does **"for"** change the meaning?

Comment: I think we need *for* to mark it adverbial. But, when we don't need it in "How long have you been out" because *how long* already mark it adverbial of duration. But this could be just my nonsense theory, though.

Comment: I think both are fine, though personally, I'm more inclined to use the former, especially in formal, written English. In informal English, I think both are fine. I think this is more about how we just tend to cut off words in informal English :D.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang So you would use "I have been out for two hours!"?

Comment: Exact-a-mundo, buckaroo! (Sorry, I had to make the minimum character quota :D.) What I had wanted to say was, "Exactly" :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for preposition (TIME/DISTANCE)

​
used to show an amount of time or distance:

> She's out of the office for a few days next week.
>   I'm just going to lie down for an hour or so.
>   I haven't played tennis for years.

We use for with a period of time to refer to duration (how long something lasts).